# Как сделать, что бы блок отображался только у определённых пользователей

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Сразу скажу, что в php я новичок.

Как сделать, что бы через `$_SESSION` php брал из БД конкретный логин и проверял, через этот ли логин пользователь авторизован, если логин другой, то делал один блок на странице невидимым.

Вот приблизительный пример (моя попытка):

PHP

```
$login = $_GET['login'];

if (!$_SESSION[$login == 'realHikkan']); {
  <<<HTML
        <style>
            .admin {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
  HTML;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="admin">
   <a href="../admin"><button class="green">Панель администратора</button></a> 
 </div>
```

Структура БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нехорошо удалять свой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1233713/  и заново создавать.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону добавления пользователей в группы, а показывать что-то можно будет определенной группе пользователей

Comment: @MichaelMiller Идея не плохая, но вопрос заключается в том, как реализовать подобный функционал (в данном случае хотя бы просто для отдельных пользователей)

Comment: @realHikkan Как Вы получаете логин юзера? Из адресной строки что ли? Нужно получить логин пользователя, потом сравнить с массивом логинов, которым нужно что-то показать и если логин текущего пользователя есть в массиве, то показать что-то

Comment: В целом розберитесь с тем что такое аутентификация и авторизация. Вам нужно почитать про роли пользователей. Например, есть  если у пользователя роль администратор то он может видеть ссылку на админпанель, если пользователь то ссылка на панель не показывается.

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk Да я в целом то в курсе, что такое аутентификация, авторизация и про роли я тоже знаю. Повторюсь, тут проблема в том, что я пока что не понимаю, как это реализовать с точки зрения кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим что у пользователя может быть только одна роль и информация про пользователей находится в таблице `users`. Тогда в  `users` добавляете еще один столбец `role`. Предположим что есть всего две роли `admin` с полным доступом ко всем ресурсам сайта и `guest` имеет ограниченый доступ к ресурсам и может только видеть информацию но не редактировать ее.

Во время авторизации на сайте вы создаете сесию с указанием какую роль имеет пользователь.
Например:

```
$user_info = [массив данных о пользователе полученый с базы];
session_start();
$_SESSION['access_role'] = $user_info['role']; // например 'admin'
```

Затем в шаблоне страницы проверяете имеет ли пользователь право видеть элемент или часть страницы. Например:

```
 <div class="nav">
   <?php 
if( $_SESSION['access_role'] == 'admin'){ // проверяем или пользователь админ
       echo '<a href="../admin"><button class="green">Панель администратора</button></a>'; 
}
else {
    echo 'То что может видеть не зарегестрированый пользователь';
} 
   ?>
 </div>
```

Ето в общих чертах как реализовать то что вам нужно.

Comment: Жи/ши пиши с гласной И

Comment: Щиро дякую, поправив!

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk Извиняюсь за крайне тупой вопрос, но как получить массив данных о пользователе для ```$user_info = [];```?

Comment: У вас данные о пользователе находятся в БД. Когда пользователь заходит на сайт он вводит логин и пароль. Следовательно Вы подключаетесь к БД, и делаете запрос в базу например через `mysqli_query()` с параметрами логин и пароль. Если есть совпадение вы получаете ответ в виде информации которую помещаете в асоциативній масив с помощью `mysqli_fetch_array`. Для получения информации с БД можно воспользоватся PDO https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php. Для лутшего понимания разберитесь сначала как работать с БД через `mysqli` https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli.php, а потом и с PDO